# How can I make CloseableHttpClient reusable?

Tags: java

I would like to make reusable `CloseableHttpClient`, am I doing it correctly?

```
public class ConnectionPool {


  private static CloseableHttpClient client;

   public ConnectionPool() {
         if (client == null) {
               PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
                connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(200);
                connectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
                connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(50000);

                client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                        .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                        .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
                        .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy())
                        .setUserTokenHandler(new UserTokenHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public Object getUserToken(HttpContext context) {
                                return null;
                            }
                        })
                        .setMaxConnTotal(200)
                        .setMaxConnPerRoute(200)
                        .setConnectionTimeToLive(50000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build();
         }
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the above code looks fine,
please also add the idle connection monitor thread so that the expired or idle connections that are more than certain time can be closed.

Some times, Server also closes the connection and it is preferred to read the server repsonse headers for the keep alive configs or timeout configs.

```
private ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy getConnectionKeepAliveStrategy(final int defaultKeepAliveDuration) {
    return new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
        @Override
        public TimeValue getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
            // Honor 'keep-alive' header
            BasicHeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(response.headerIterator("Keep-Alive"));
            long defaultDuration = defaultKeepAliveDuration;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                HeaderElement he = it.next();
                String param = he.getName();
                String value = he.getValue();
                if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                    try {
                        defaultDuration = Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                    }
                } else if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("max")) {
                    try {
                        // if the max requests that can be sent are coming to 25, better to close the connection and
                        // create a new connection to void server abruptly closing the connections.
                        // as multiple threads are using the same connection object.
                        if (Long.parseLong(value) <= 25) {
                            defaultDuration = 1;
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
            return TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(defaultDuration);
        }
    };
}
```

while calling the httpClient.execute method,we can send the HttpClientContext to the execute method.
we can set the Socket factory to the HttpClientContext in the below way.Use the HttpClientContext and pass that as argument in the httpClient.execute method.

```
public static HttpClientContext getHttpClientContext(SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory) {
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()).register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
        HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        clientContext.setAttribute("http.socket-factory-registry", socketFactoryRegistry);
        return clientContext;
    }
```

the sample http client call will be like below:

```
closeableHttpClient.execute(httpReq, HttpClientContextHelper.getHttpClientContext(sslsf), responseHandler);
```

code for dynamic SSL connection Socket factory based on the SSL configs

private SSLConnectionSocketFactory createSslConnectionSocketFactory(final ProviderRequest request) throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException,
KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, Exception {

```
if (request.getSslConfig() != null) {
    //create respective ssl socket factory with the ssl variables
    return sslsf;
} else {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {

        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }};
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sc, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    return sslsf;
}
```

}

Comment: I just noticed that i have different request that has different URL, and some of those requires SSL. How can I set sslfactory?

Comment: you can actually send the http client context when we are calling the execute request.
added the sample code above

Comment: how about for those doesnt require SSL?

Comment: added the same code for creation of the SSL socket connection factory with and without ssl